# How to know which button "Leave the page" or "Stay on this page" is clicked when using the exit confirmation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Using javascript, when the tab is closed the alert is shown to user to confirm leaving the page , but the problem is i want to detect which button "Leave this page" or "stay on this page" is clicked as i have to perform some function based on this.

```
<script>
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return 'are you sure';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Post some code.. You might be using some code to display this message?

Comment: written the code, i just want to know which button is clicked.

Comment: I'm not sure you can really do this considering if they press "Leave this page" they'll no longer be on your site?

Comment: my client wants to redirect to another link when clicking on stay on this page

Comment: you need to identify those buttons, as there is no way to find which button event raise page redirect request.

Comment: how to identify those buttons

Comment: This post should have the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835217/is-there-a-callback-for-cancelling-window-onbeforeunload