# Exit page redirect with confirmation box leave and cancel javascript. How to achieve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that has a exit page confirmation box which is this code

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return 'You have unsaved changes!';
}
</script>
```

Now, i want to add a redirection. For example i close the page, a confirmation box will appear that has a **Leave** and **Cancel** button. When **Cancel** is clicked it will redirect to a page. Then, when **Leave** button is click a page will just close.

Please Help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a callback for cancelling window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835217/is-there-a-callback-for-cancelling-window-onbeforeunload)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Actually I believe this question does not answer OP's problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [confirm() on window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132060/confirm-on-window-onbeforeunload)

Comment: You're just not passing the event parameter into the function. You should do something like `window.onbeforeunload = function(event){ ... });`

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski OP asks about how to react to the user cancelling the dialog that is triggered by the `onbeforeunload` event. The duplicate question asks exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly this is impossible. The only way to prevent closing or refreshing the page is by using `beforeunload` event.

The little trick I used was to bind an event to all `a` tags on my page and to `F5` button, that displays a modal with confirmation. And then if `cancel`button was clicked I would prevent the default action. So page was not refreshed or redirected.

But as to closing the tab there is no way to achieve what you would want. It's a pitty though because many people struggle with this.

Comment: how about... when closing tab a confirmation box will appear that has **Close** and **go to this page**? I tried adding 'window.location' on my code but it doesn't work

Comment: As I said, this is not possible. Sorry.. I know because I spent many hours on a very similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'undefined') {
    window.addEventListener = function(e, callback) {
        return window.attachEvent('on' + e, callback);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Dialog Text Here';
});
```

If that doesn't work, then you can try something really simple like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) for some useful documentation. If you need to customize it further, use plugins like [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/) for that. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132131/4721369) too and the possible duplicates linked below your question.