# JavaScript for "Do you want to leave this site? Leave or Stay"

Tags: javascript, html, lms

Currently, I'm using this code:-

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => { 
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = '';
});
```

[image]

But it does not appear what I want. What else JavaScript code available?

[image]

Comment: see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript before leaving the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page)

Comment: Please follow the prompt and replace `enter image description here` with what to expect when following the hyperlink.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835217/is-there-a-callback-for-cancelling-window-onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => { 
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = '';
});
```

Will not do anything as `preventDefault()` cannot stop page from loading. Instead you should use `return false;`. Also with that nothing else can come in the function and the user can just choose whether to stay or leave. So your code will become:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => { 
    return false;
});
```

If you add anything else in the function your code will not work.

Comment: Thanks to help me. Actually, I want to enable this function when leaving the page, but it appears different from what I want. I want the functions appear this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCyfg.jpg